# faço o butão com windows print e so imprimi rodape

Tags: javascript, ajax

o windows print so manda o final da tela não consigo entender o por que

Comprovante de Inscrição
                                        **Edital Processo Seletivo Simplificado da Saúde - 01/2021**
                                    
                                    
                                        Data: 2021-02-01 15:26:18

```
                            <hr>

                            <div class="row invoice-info">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 invoice-col">
                                    Nome:
                                    <address>
                                        <strong>LUIZA CERQUEIRA DOS SANTOS</strong><br>
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                            
                                <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
                                    Nº Inscrição:
                                    <address>
                                        <strong>ps.02.2021.5355458</strong><br>
                                    </address>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
                                    Nº CPF:
                                    <address>
                                        <strong>054.741.695-40</strong><br>
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row invoice-info">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 invoice-col">
                                    Cargo:
                                    <address>
                                        <strong>ASSISTENTE ADMINISTRATIVO ESCOLAR</strong><br>
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                            
                                <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
                                    Local:
                                    <address>
                                        <strong>ESCOLAS SEDE</strong><br>
                                    </address>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
                                    Tipo Cargo:
                                    <address>
                                        <strong>AMPLA CONCORRÊNCIA</strong><br>
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.print();"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">
                                    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Generate PDF
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->
                            
                            <!-- this row will not appear when printing -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                   
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<!-- Main Footer -->
<footer class="main-footer">
        <strong>Copyright © 2021 Prefeitura Municipal de Porto Seguro.</strong>
        Todos os direitos reservados.
        <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            <b>Versão</b> 1.0.0-rc
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: o `window.print()` as vezes imprime uma área visível do html e não a página toda, faça um teste adicionado isso ao seu css: `body, html,  { height: 100%;  width: 100%; }`. Se esse formato ficar ruim para navegação, coloque esse estilo num css para "a visão de impressão", assim: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilodeimpressao.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>`

Comment: não resolveu o problema

Comment: Amigo oq você está tentando fazer? Quanto mais detalhes melhor.